Wedge constrained motion problem
I was solving this question on wedge-constrained motion:

Q)Acceleration of blocks A and C are 2a and 3a respectively.
Find the acceleration of block B.


My Approach:
Below I'm attaching a diagram with reference to my equations

Method 1) In ground frame
I analyze the motion as follows:

So, as the tension acts on the pulley, wedge accelerates towards the negative x-direction as pulley is directly connected to wedge.

And the block B would have accelerations in x and y directions with respect to ground which I have assumed as $a_{Bx}$ and $a_{by}$.

As string is inextensible we can equate the accelerations of points 1 and 2 as marked in the diagram, so we can write the equation


$$\color{red}{2a = a_{By}cosθ - a_{Bx}}$$

We can write one more equation by using the fact that the wedge C and block B are in contact. So, for not losing contact the acceleration of wedge C and block B along the common normal must be equal.

Equating them we get :
$$\color{red}{3asin(θ) = a_{Bx}sin(θ) + a_{By}cos(θ)}$$
Now we have two variables $a_{Bx}$ and $a_{By}$ and two equations, which can be solved to get a_{B} i.e equal to vector sum of $a_{Bx}$ and $a_{By}$.
Method 2) In wedge frame
If we observe the problem in wedge frame its quite simple as then if we see in 'dt' time then C would move 3 units towards negative x-direction and A would move 2 units towards positive x-direction.
So, overall the string length would reduced by 5 units. To conserve length of the string it needs to increase by 5 units which will be attained by block B moving 5 units along the incline.
So the acceleration of block B must be 5a along the incline in wedge frame.
Now as we know from relative motion that
$$\color{blue}{\bar{a}_{B} = \bar{a}_{BC} + \bar{a}_{C}}$$.
(Note that it is a vector sum)
We know that the angle between $\bar{a}_{BC}$ and $\bar{a}_{C}$ is $180 - θ$. So by summing up vectorially we get acceleration of block B as
$$\color{red}{a_B = \sqrt{34 - 15cos(θ)}}$$
My Doubt:
1)In the first method we have lengthy calculations for getting those $a_{Bx}$ and $a_{By}$. Second method is quite quick and easier to analyze. So, Are both the methods correct?
2)What can be an alternative approach to minimize calculation and solve faster.

Yes, both of your method is correct. Here is answer to your doubts.

In the first method you have solved the question in ground frame of reference, for which the motion of block B is in some direction which is unknown to us and is quite complicated to solve, therefore you have to indulge in length calculations while solving in ground frame.

But while solving the question in the reference frame attached to the wedge, the motion of the block B is known to us that is along the inclined plane of the wedge and hence this saves us from lengthy calculations and make the question easier.(Some questions are difficult to solve in one reference frame but are easier solving in another reference frame)

Questions can be solved in many reference frames, but this type of question is generally solved in ground frame or wedge frame as these are the most convenient ways.

